# Несколько модальных окон в одной вьюхе

Tags: yii2

Yii2. У меня есть view карточки контрагента (user). В ней помимо самой таблицы, хранящей данные клиента, есть две связанные таблицы, хранящие:
а) данные о событиях (истории работы с ним) (event);
б) список контактных лиц контрагента (person).

Я хочу на этом view использовать несколько `yii\bootstrap\Modal;`
Т.е. мне надо, чтобы одна кнопка открыла в модальном окне форму добавления/редактирования событий, другая в другом модальном окне открывала форму добавления/редактирования контактных лиц, третья кнопка открывала модальное окно редактирования информации о сомом контрагенте.

Есть блоки

```
<?php
    Modal::begin([
    ....
    echo ххххххххххххххххххх;
    Modal::end();  
?>
```

вставлять вместо "echo хххх" наборы `<?= $form->field($model,'...` я не хочу, т.к. поля в таблице могут добавляться и надо помнить, что у тебя есть модальные окна и в них потом править, да и не хорошо это. Мне надо что-то типа render, чтоб получилось что-то типа

```
<?php
    Modal::begin([
    ....
    render('_form', ['model' => $model]); - event
    Modal::end();  
?>
<?php
    Modal::begin([
    ....
    render('_form', ['model' => $model]); - person
    Modal::end();  
?>
<?php
    Modal::begin([
    ....
    render('_form', ['model' => $model]); - user
    Modal::end();  
?>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как подключить эти виды?

Comment: Есть же вьюшка страницы редактирования модели. Вот ее и отрисовать в модалке.

Comment: вы вопрос не поняли. У меня не вопрос что отрисовать, у меня вопрос как подключить эти вьюшки, учитывая, что мне надо сделать подключение нескольких вью от разных моделей на одной странице

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так брать файл вида и выводить на странице

```
echo $this->render('_formEvent', ['model' => $event]);
echo $this->render('_formPerson', ['model' => $person]);
echo $this->render('_formUser', ['model' => $user]);
```