# правильное использование нескольких _form

Tags: yii2

У меня есть модели: User, Event, Person.

User - это юзер (например, "Магазин "Ромашка"").

Event - это события, которые фиксируют каждый контакт с User.

Person - это сотрудники "Магазина "Ромашка"", с которыми происходят контакты.

Для создания каждой сущности прописаны отдельные _form.php с набором различных условий.

Алгоритм создания юзера такой: 
1. Создаём юзера.
2. открываем созданного юзера, создаём в нём Person
3. открываем юзера, создаём Event с выбранной Person

Когда юзер создан и с ним уже идёт работа, то всё хорошо, но первоначальное создание карточки Клиента неудобное. Все три _form можно заполнить сразу при создании User.

Работать с несколькими моделями одновременно я умею, но у меня вопрос другого плана.

Как в form создания User подтянуть уже созданные form для Event и Person не дублируя код, а именно подтянув имеющиеся form? Надо подтянуть так, чтоб использовались все те условия, которые существуют для заполнения форм Event и Person.

Если использовать простой рендер типа

```
echo $this->render('_formEvent', ['model' => $event]);
echo $this->render('_formPerson', ['model' => $person]);
echo $this->render('_formUser', ['model' => $user]);
```

это не совсем хорошо, т.к. возникают как минимум 2 проблемы:

1. подтягиваются три кнопки "Отправить"
2. возникают сложности при передаче данных из модели в модель.

Да и очерёдность сохранения данных мне нужна. Так как при сохранении этой конструкции мне надо, чтоб по хронологии после нажатия "Сохранить" сначала сохранился юзер, взялся его айдишник и использовался в таблице person для сохранения персоны этого юзера.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Несколько модальных окон в одной вьюхе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931807/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8c%d1%8e%d1%85%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте поведения [behaviors Yii2](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/concept-behaviors/)

Поведения идеально работают с событиями. Например:

```
namespace app\components;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\base\Behavior;

class MyBehavior extends Behavior
{
    // ...

    public function events()
    {
        return [
            ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE => 'beforeValidate',
        ];
    }

    public function beforeValidate($event)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: не совсем как мне помогут события и поведения. Мне в одном месте надо вывести три формы. При этом должна быть одна кнопка "Сохранить" на всех.